# The objection function of Lasso in sklearn: why the coefficient 1/(2*n_samples) is there?

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso

In sklearn Lasso (link below):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html?highlight=lasso#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso

, there is the coefficient 1/(2*n_samples) in the objective function:
[image]

Why does Sklearn insert the coefficient there?

Answer (score 1):

When minimizing squared error, you would often see $\tfrac{1}{2}$ there, because derivative of $\tfrac{1}{2} x^2$ is $x$, while for $x^2$  alone it's $2x$, so the first expression leads to more "elegant" formulation. As for `n_samples`, it is to make the loss function an average, so that it doesn't depend on sample size. Both are meant for humans to make reading the code and interpreting results easier, but doesn't matter from optimization point of view, since those are just constants. You can find nice explanation in [this thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/why-do-cost-functions-use-the-square-error).